# how to twitter login/auth with Javascript SDK from Parse-Server parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, parse-platform, parse-server

this question is kind of broad but I have no idea where should I start.

I have a single page app written in AngularJS and the backend is running on Parse-Server (parse.com) http://parseplatform.github.io/. I already did all the authentication for facebook and now I want to allow my users to login with twitter but I have no idea where to start because Parse-Server doesn't support twitter natively in the same way as facebook.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My personal suggestion would be to do this via cloud code in your `cloud/main.js` file. This way you can update existing user tables etc once a user has successfully authenticated.

Here is a some examples of that. They old, but concept is the same. Just dont forget to use `{ useMasterKey: true }` when querying or modifying the user class.

https://github.com/sreejithbnaick/Twitter-OAuth-1.1-Signature-Generator-js

https://medium.com/@nannerb/tutorial-storing-tweets-in-parse-via-the-twitter-api-9fe2ee092013#.hlkum966e

https://gist.github.com/aleclarson/8892714

Twitter Docs:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: thanks @Cliffordwh, did you used this method before? I see the articles are from back 2015 when parse-server wasn't announced yet, do you think this will work with the new open-source version parse-server?

Comment: Yes, one of the reason cloud code works so well! I did the same for my google plus users!

Comment: Just remember to use masterKey when modifying the users class!

Comment: thanks! in the past I found hard working with external libraries in the cloud/main.js because of the express dependencies, but now that is not a problem anymore with parse-server. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Spot on!  parse-server cloud code for me personally is a must! You welcome and all the best!